# Selecting files in IPython notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is there a good way for me to select files on the host file-system through the IPython notebook? I was hoping for some sort of widget based solution.

For example, I want to train a machine learning algorithm using some files, and I want to be able to select which CSV files to use for training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are no widget (yet) but maybe you will do it :-) otherwise on *nix like with IPython you can do things like :

```
files = !ls *.train.csv
for f in files:
  ...
```

and it will do what you expect